# Ruby Hash classs method has_key? vs method member?

Tags: ruby, methods, hash

Is there any difference between the two methods for the Ruby Hash, or is it just "there is more than 1 way to do it"?
I could not see any measureable difference between the two.
Thanks,

Comment: As per https://apidock.com/ruby/Hash/has_key%3F and http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Hash.html#method-i-member-3F, they look to return the same results.

Comment: FYI `Hash.instance_method(:has_key?) == Hash.instance_method(:member?) #=> true`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To see the method definition's source code see documentation, find the method you're looking for then click on the method to expand to see the actual source code:

https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Hash.html#method-i-member-3F

```
    rb_hash_has_key(VALUE hash, VALUE key)
    {
        if (!RHASH(hash)->ntbl)
            return Qfalse;
        if (st_lookup(RHASH(hash)->ntbl, key, 0)) {
            return Qtrue;
        }
        return Qfalse;
    }
```

https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Hash.html#method-i-has_key-3F

```
    rb_hash_has_key(VALUE hash, VALUE key)
    {
        if (!RHASH(hash)->ntbl)
            return Qfalse;
        if (st_lookup(RHASH(hash)->ntbl, key, 0)) {
            return Qtrue;
        }
        return Qfalse;
    }
```

Answer (score 11):

According to the [Ruby source](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/798316eac260e3cd683da2be23fef53ee64cee00/hash.c#L4710), `has_key?`, `key?`, `include?` and `member?` are the same implementation.